# Django forms resize CharField/Textarea fields

Tags: python, django, django-forms, textarea

I'm currently developing a web app with django and I have some forms where the users can enter a lot of text (up to 5.000 chars). I'm doing this using a CharField in forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class text_form(forms.Form):
    ...

    longer_text = forms.CharField(
        max_length=5000,
        widget=forms.Textarea(
            attrs={
                'rows':10,
                'cols':2,
                'data-length':5000,
            }),
        help_text='Some help text',
        label = 'Label Text',
        required=True
        )
```

The problems I'm facing right now (and I couldn't solve them even though I read a lot of related SO question) are:

1) I want the users to see a larger field (multiple rows) where they can insert text. Right now it's about maybe two rows and doesn't resize regardless of what I insert as rows value in attrs.

2) The users should be able to use the Enter key on their keyboard within those textareas to make a linebreak

Any ideas how to achieve this? And another thought: Maybe it already works and this is a browser related thing? Thanks!

Comment: have you tried widget=forms.Textarea in forms?

Comment: try crispy filter with forms

Comment: @bmons yes I tried that as you can see in my question

Comment: @AnoopKGeorge I will have a look into that. Thanks.